# Is it possible to uninstall a software from Ubuntu 12.04 installed on USB stick?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I have Installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB stick. Now, is it possible to uninstall a software *(the software is remastersys)* from this USB stick installation? How can I do that?

Comment: How was the software installed, and what is it?

Comment: @Mitch Actually, I have customized Ubuntu 12.04 ISO with remastersys and install the ISO on a USB stick. Now I want to remove remastersys from the USB stick installation.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot using the usb stick.
- run `sudo apt-get remove remastersys remastersys-gtk`
- Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and comment out OR remove line containing remastersys reference.

Comment: I have done all the steps you mentioned here. But no positive result. Remastersys is still on that USB stick as an installed software.

Comment: what was output when you excuted the remove commands?

Comment: Output was very positive. It was showing uninstall is completed successfully and freed 3177 KB space. I have also deleted the line containing remastersys reference and save sources.list file successfully. But final result was negative. remastersys is still on the stick as installed software.

Comment: Still I am facing the problem.Would you help me please?

Comment: You said you have installed it.But the problem suggest you have a live usb disk. Please remember installation in USB doesn't mean creating a live usb disk.

Comment: I see. Could you please tell me, what's the difference between these two?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/156026/35775. Basically live means no write operation to system files. Only temporary storage are used.