# automatic Boot up from USB

Tags: boot, usb, default

So I have ubuntu 12.04 on my usb, it loads perfectly and works.
When I boot up my laptop (Windows 7) a menu box appears to ask how I want to run ubuntu, the first selection is Default which I use, the next being somewhere along the lines of "Install ubuntu", then a load of other selections

What I ask is, is there a way for Ubuntu to boot up without bringing up the box? Like when I boot up with my normal operating system...

Sorry if I'm confusing ;_;

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal for some explanations on different types of Ubuntu installations in USB.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of that box by [installing Ubuntu on your USB disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) instead of just running a Live session.

All you basically have to do is boot Ubuntu from another USB disk or a Live DVD and use the USB drive as the target device during installation.

Comment: That means I'll have to buy another flash drive? ._. I guess it's worth a shot though

Comment: Nah just means you'll have to save your data somewhere, format the disk, and follow the procedure (directions for formatting the disk are part of the procedure). There are many pros to doing it this way, for example you'll also be able to receive updates and do everything you can do in a normal installation including doing a release upgrade. (Though you'll have to watch your disk usage and use Bleachbit once in a while and maybe delete old kernels).

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer is probably the decent way of doing it, I guess it could be accomplished by editing the GRUB on the USB disc

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Under "Changing boot options **Permanently** for an Existing Installation" and simply deleting the other options, or setting the default and setting the time out very low, so it almost instantly skips the menu...

Hope it helps!