# Save changes on Flash Drive

Tags: 13.10

I have my Ubuntu installed on a flash drive. When doing any change to it, the changes are lost when booting. Is there a way to save the changes on the USB?

Thank you,
Fahd

Comment: did you installed ubuntu on usb or you just created an ubuntu live usb?

Comment: It must be a live usb

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your Ubuntu live usb persistant.So that any installed programs won't lost after rebooting.

[What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal)

see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal) for how to make livecd persistence using loopback file.