# Running Ubuntu on 16GB Thumb drive

Tags: 12.10, usb, live-usb, usb-drive, usb-creator

I'm brand new- An Ubuntu convert- and I've been able to so far figure out how to burn the OS onto a DVD, and also how I can get it onto a thumb drive. I've even gotten it to work on both.

However, what I am concerned with is this: Can I continue to run Ubuntu ONLY via my thumb drive, and if so, when I get the screen telling me I can either "try Ubuntu" or install it, which do I choose? I've only done the former option, but if I do the latter, am I going to wipe my comp or will it actually only install on the thumb drive? I guess I'm wondering if I can treat my thumb drive like an external hard drive and just have it on there, so that I can use it when I want and then go back to my other OS when it's not plugged in.

Thanks for your help, all. Hopefully I'm making enough sense that you guys/gals know what I'm asking.

Comment: Try using a persistent install. Direct install is not recommend for reasons as stated [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/295776/17722)

Comment: It is not straightforward but it's possible. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to run from your thumb drive as is, this is a Persistent install if you have provided "extra space".

I am not afraid of wearing out thumb drives from overuse, my entertainment center runs off one and has been used daily for years.

If you do not want the Try/Install screen, replace the contents of the file syslinux.cfg with:

[CODE]    default persistent
    label persistent
      say Booting a persistent Ubuntu session...
      kernel /casper/vmlinuz
      append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --[/CODE]

You can also do a Full install to thumb drive.
Just disable your internal HDD and install to an 8GB or larger thumb drive as normal.