# AMD Radeon HD 6850M driver compatability

Tags: 14.04, radeon, compatibility

I'M HOPELESS. I'm also dramatic. I've read a couple articles/posts about this issue but I have no idea what I'm doing and don't know how to install drivers. Does anyone know how to download a driver that will best utilize my AMD Radeon HD 6850M graphics card? Also, is this issue related to Unity freezing after opening my laptop from suspend/during LightDM/randomly? ah.

I'm running an Acer Aspire 7750G

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/442930/which-proprietary-driver-should-i-activate/443305#443305 It might help you install the driver .

Answer (score 0):

open **system setting - software & update - additional drivers**

- then choose- fglx (property)[image]
- not slove choose another option and try again
- need internet connection to do this operation