# Latest ATI drivers for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, amd-graphics

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed the ATI drivers from *"Software Update"* -> *"Additional drivers"*, but on the official ATI website the latest Linux beta drivers have a newer version.

If that version supports kernel 3.13 can I download the drivers and install them from there since they are the latest?

Comment: I suppose my answer here might help you install the driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/442930/which-proprietary-driver-should-i-activate/443305#443305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the proprietary ATI driver in Additional Drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 is fglrx-updates 13.3. fglrx-updates 13.3 supports the 3.13 Linux kernel. The latest version of the AMD Catalyst Driver for Linux from the [AMD Graphics Drivers and Software](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) website is 14.4. I don't think there's really much point in installing the AMD Catalyst Driver in Ubuntu 14.04 unless you tried the fglrx-updates driver first and found something wrong with it.

Comment: So there is really nothing to worry about  ? but still I don't understand why on the AMD website it says it supports Ubuntu 12.04.3, 12.04.4 and 13.10 and not also 14.04 since it supports kernel 3.13 Thanks!

Comment: I installed the AMD Catalyst driver in Ubuntu 12.04 because I checked at the AMD Graphics Drivers and Software website and then installed the driver for my new graphics card that was recommended there. Now that I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I already have installed a newer version of fglrx-updates than that from the Ubuntu Software Center, and it is working fine.