# Remove the first window when starting from usb

Tags: live-usb, system-installation, usb-creator

I burn Ubuntu in a pen-drive. But each time I start with Ubuntu I need to change the configuration and select the option that I want to try Ubuntu not install removing my laptop operative system.

What can I do?

I found somewhere that an option is to install the system on the pendrive.
But I [found](https://askubuntu.com/a/295776/270501) I need 8GB on the pen-drive, and following the [manual](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) I set just ~2500MB of persistent size for storing (step 4 in the window of the Universal USB Installer). How can I install it persistent on the pen-drive? Or I have already done so?

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a persistent file. Any apps you install, documents you store on the casper filesystem, or configuration changes you make *will be kept*. This is not the same as a full system, which is designed for permanent use.

To see how to install Ubuntu to your USB without it being a Live USB, see [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator). But what you will find there is that all you have to do is basically start the Ubuntu installation process from *another* Live USB and select your other USB as the target for installation.

If you want to experiment with this but your USB stick is under 4.4 GB, you could give the [minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) a shot.

Comment: Well I changed the keyboard configuration and it was not kept. I don't know if I did something wrong or what.
So I can have a Live USB, a Persistent USB and a Installed USB...
Then for the Installed I need ~8GB or at least ~4.4GB according to the post linked. And in the key I have it now is just of 4GB...

Comment: @Llopis There are cheap keys on eBay.

Comment: @searchfqold The problem is not the price, I also have other keys, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: Well, actually in my persistent file, I do not have internet connection. And I am suspecting I did not everything right because some changes are not kept. Or at least I don't understand what casper files are.