# Can I create an Ubuntu installation in my pendrive but not volatile in order to keep my data in a future boot?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

Ubuntu LiveCD works on volatile (temporarily) memory, it's RAM. That's ok.

However I want to really make an installation on my pendrive, in order to keep my data in a future boot.

Can I install the Ubuntu normally on my pendrive?!
Which are the possibilities to do that?!

Comment: I think [the answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal) will help you. If not, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think whether this is possible or not depends on your pendrive's storing capacity.

You can take a look at the official guide to create a bootable Ubuntu USB here (pay attention to **step 6**)

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu