# USB Boot Drive is not recognized from Windows computers

Tags: boot, usb

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 to my 16GB PNY flash drive, to use as a boot disk for my laptop. Now, it is running ludicrously slow, no matter what, so I am trying to re-install Ubuntu, but when I plug my boot disk in to any other computers (usually running windows 7), it is not assigned a drive letter. The computer will install drivers for it, but when I try to access it, the drive is not there.

EDIT1: The drive was formatted for NTFS during the initial install.

Comment: If it's not formatted to ntfs or fat32, then Windows won't read it.

Comment: ... or FAT16 or FAT12 ;-)

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes more sense. I did a full install, yeah. Do you know how I can change it from EXT4 to NTFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From your comments above, it looks like you did a complete install of Ubuntu on the 16GB USB drive.**

There are two methods to put Ubuntu in an USB. The first is a LiveUSB that is used to install Ubuntu in the hard drive. The second is a full install, where the USB works like a hard drive. See [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776)

A full install on a 16GB USB, formatted the USB drive `ext4`. This is the format Ubuntu (Linux in general) requires. Ubuntu cannot be installed in `NTFS`. The `ext4` partition where Ubuntu is installed cannot be changed to `NTFS`. If you do, you will lose all the ownership and permission information Ubuntu needs to work properly. Then Ubuntu won't work.

On the other hand, Windows does not know about `ext4` format and thus can't read.

**Solutions:**

There are third party extensions you can install in Windows to make it read `ext4` partition. [See 3 ways to access your Linux partition from Windows.](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/)

Alternately, recreate the USB drive.

You can create a small (say 512MB) `FAT32` partition in the beginning of the USB drive to share some data. This should be the first primary partition partition for Windows to see it. You can leave the rest of the 16GB unallocated for Ubuntu installation to find it. Or you can choose "Something else..." during Ubuntu installation and format the remaining part of the drive `ext4` and select mount-point `/`.

Hope this helps