# With an Ubuntu live USB, does the flash stick get written to?

Tags: live-usb, flash, persistence

If I am running Ubuntu or one of its offshoots "live" from a USB flash stick, does the stick get written to, or are there only read operations?

How about if persistence is disabled?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

From the first line, it seems that the Live CD/USB is read only unless you add persistent file storage. That link should show you how to do so.