# How do I save data that I create in a LiveCD session?

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on my 8 GB USB on an HP laptop with Windows 8.1 preinstalled.

How do I get Ubuntu to be able to save programs that I download, Firefox bookmarks, or anything else that I create? Do I have to install it to a partition or can I just have it on my USB?

I really wanted Ubuntu on a partition because I want more space. However, I don't know what to do. I tried searching for tutorials but wasn't able to find anything specifically matching what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. Use persistence - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence or install it to usb. IMO a full install is the better, more reliable option.

Comment: What is "IMO" full install.

Comment: @BrandonBootz IMO = ["In my opinion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_I#IMO).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal)