# Can I use rest of the USB with persistent Live USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, flash, persistence

I want to use Ubuntu on USB flash memory. I dont want to start "from scratch" everytime I boot Ubuntu from that USB. I decided to make a persistent USB flash. My question is: Can I still use flash memory for storing data and moving it from computer to computer without making Ubuntu corrupted or something like that? So my flash memory is 16GB and I make persistent 4GB, I can use normally other 12GBs.

Comment: Yes you can if you install Ubuntu to the flash drive.

Comment: So if I install it to the flash I will be able to continue using it as normal but I would also be able to boot Ubuntu from it.

Comment: That would be correct as long as the boot file is saved to the flash drive.

Comment: Good information here -》 http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I engaged the exact procedure that you propose without incident.

As I recall, I was able to do this with PNY, SanDisk and Cruzer.

However, in the process of using several USB flashdrives for perhaps a dozen installs, some of which were reinstalls, I encountered mixed performace from various USB sticks.Some of them have been retired as unusable, but when they burnt out the cause was not as far as I have been able to ascertain, related to mixed usage.

Thus, while it is perfectly possible to go ahead and use a flash drive for both Live session boot-up of Ubuntu AND also for data storage, there is always the prospect that you may either lose data or overwrite or otherwise corrupt one of the boot up files or data files. Back up, back up and backup.

In my practice, I finally broke down and started using Live DVD's for installs so that I could use the flashdrives uncluttered. An added advantage is that I always know exactly which ISO and which burn I used for the install. It is written right there on the DVD that this ISO was installed on that computer on such and such a date. With the USB's, it is more difficult to keep track of which ISO was installed on which computer, although it is of course still possible.

Additional information which MIGHT be pertinent to further questions should you encounter problems would be:

- brand and model of the particular flash drives
- capacity, especially as older smaller USB's may be more prone to glitches, perhaps
- the manner in which the flashdrive is formatted, eg. FAT32, ntfs,etc. and perhaps how it was formatted (quick format on windows vs. slow format, format via Ubuntu, etc.)
- whether it is USB 2.x or USB 3.x
- whether the "data files" include executables or linux files
- whether there are executables such as U3 which might interfere since they attempt to interject themselves between the USB partitions and the user
- whether or not you have permitted Windows USB-repair to run, which IMVVHO may be unwise lgiven that MS is widely suspected of injecting Linux-averse obstacles into situations in which there is no other clear basis
- which installation process you use to create the USB stick, eg. UNetbootin,  YUMI,etc.

All of these variables may affect your outcome, and you may wish to take note of remarks from other users who express better luck with some USB brands than others.USB flashdrives have a limited burn time. Subject to the **backup** warnings, your answer is yes you certainly can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think that full instalation is what I need.

Comment: Eventually yes. Have you decided on LTS or the 15?

Answer (score 1):

The first partition on a Persistent flash drive is FAT32, it is the only partition visible to Windows.

You can access data on this partition while the drive is plugged into a Windows computer.

If you need to access data stored on this partition while booted from the flash drive, you can find it at filesystem/cdrom.

Edit

If a Full install is what you want:

Start by formatting your flash drive as NTFS if it is large, otherwise leave as FAT32.

When you get to partitioning select "Something else".

Leave the space desired for the first partition as FAT32 or NTFS, this is your Windows/Linux data partition.

Make the remaining space ext4 and use for "/" (with a little space for swap if you want to allow hibernation).

Make sure the boot loader is installed to the root of the USB drive.

Continue with install.

Finished drive will have a partition accessible to Windows and Linux (and OSX if FAT32).

Edit:

Windows 10 can see FAT and NTFS partitions regardless of partition order.