# Install Ubuntu in Flash Drive to work in any computer

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, usb-drive

How to make Ubuntu Installed flash drive bootable in any PC?

I am new user to Ubuntu and started loving it. I'm using Toshiba Satellite C840 and using Ubuntu 16.04 as my primary OS in dual boot mode.

However, due to the inconvenience in carrying my Laptop everywhere, I've bought a 32GB flash drive and installed Ubuntu 16.04 in it with my all necessary apps and settings.

Since my Laptop is already using dual boot with Win7, my flash drive Ubuntu boots properly.

My question is - instead of carrying my Laptop, if I want to carry my USB flash drive (where Ubuntu 16.04 is already installed) and try to boot it in any other PC (say, in my cousin's pc) , will it work? If not, then how to make it work properly?

Comment: Also see [the difference between persistent and full install in USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work. But you will probably have problems with different drivers for different hardware which could lead to some crashes or (especially when it comes to graphics drivers) the system won't start and leaves you with a black screen.

Comment: Will work?
Since my cousin's PC don't use dual boot mood and don't have grub, will not it be a problem?

Comment: It will work you don't need grub. You just have to push a button on start up (like the bios button something like F11 or F12) and go to the boot menu. There you should be able to choose which partition or usb stick you want to boot from.

Comment: and by the way if that fails you might want to disable secure boot in the bios because it blocks booting from external drives!

Comment: Okye, fine. That is what I wanted to know. Thank you. Anyway, how to avoid some basic hardware problems? I'm not asking for all hardwares' drivers installed in my flash drive. But, will it be problematic for basic hardware? Actually, I want to prepare my flash drive in a way so that wherever I go, I can comfortably use my own OS. I am not interested in using someone else's OS. My Ubuntu is always with me in pocket. That is what my intention is.

Thanks

Comment: The only problem on ubuntu would be the graphics driver I guess. Just always use the standard one and don't install any other amd/ nvidia graphics driver. Then you should be fine on almost any pc!

Comment: Nice point. I will remove my special graphic driver from my flash. Anyway, do you have any idea on - how to disable secure booting? Is there any universal process? Or will it be suggested by the BIOS itself when entering in the BIOS menu?

Comment: If you try to boot from the usb drive in most cases it says something like 'Can't boot from external drive disable secure boot first'. Then you have to go the bios and somewhere either under 'security' or 'boot' there will be an option 'disable/enable secure boot'. Just disable it and you should be able to boot from the usb drive.