# Booting Ubuntu from USB not keeping time setting or user info

Tags: boot, usb, time

I have made a bootable USB using RUFUS 3.1, Ubuntu boots fine, it just wont keep my time/date settings or my username and password info. I don't know what else its not keeping these are just the only things I've noticed so far. I'm new to Ubuntu and the Linux environment, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe you may need to enable persistent storage on the USB: https://usbubuntu.wordpress.com/make-it-persistent/

Comment: 1. You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a *persistent live* system in a USB drive; 2. You can make an *installed Ubuntu system* from a live-only or persistent live USB drive into an internal drive (standard) or into another external [USB or eSATA] drive (special). See this link and links from it: [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used RUFUS, but it is my understanding is it creates a bootable Live USB not a full Ubuntu system.

If this is the case, the USB is to be used for trying out Ubuntu on your computer to find out if your computer and Ubuntu would work together. The USB can also be used to install Ubuntu in your hard disk. Think of this USB like the Windows 10 installation DVD. Like the DVD, any changes you make will be lost when you turn the computer off or reboot.

There are two ways to get around this:

1. Persistence

A live USB with persistence has a virtual file system in a file that stores the personal information or documents you save.

See https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ for more information

2. Full install

A full install of Ubuntu in an USB involves using two USB drives, one to install from and another to install to. The process is similar to installing to the internal drive.

See [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) for how to do this.

You may also find [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal) useful.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/   Followed this, still not giving me the GNU GRUB menu. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The link in the comment above and the question don't match. Either edit the original question with new information or ask a new question.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my laptops HDD, in effort to be able to dual boot with Windows 10. I followed the instruction in that link for installation, but my laptop is still booting Windows 10 and not Ubuntus grub menu where I can select which OS to boot. I’m trying to figure how to change the boot sequence in the UEFI settings so it will load Ubuntu first, then give me the option to choose between Ubuntu or Win10.

Comment: @MichaelYates this is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. You seem to be trying to ask a new question in the comments to the answer to your first question. If you think the answer to your first question is correct. Please put the green check mark on the left margin of the answer. This will help others and indicate that your question has been answered to your satisfaction. Please search for (for example) **how can I repair grub** for answers to questions similar to your new question. If your searches do not get you the right answer, then ask a new question.