# bootable USB with UPDATABLE Changes

Tags: 14.04, usb, live-usb, usb-installation

Is it possible to create bootable USB disk which would be UPDATED in the very same way as HDD disk does? I.e. when I modify a file in the booted USB, the USB will remember all the changes afterwards in next boots with it?
OR when I install new packages, the USB will be updated accordingly for ever?

The answers there are much too complex for me.

HOW at least it is called in the slang that isntalation that allows these possibilities of updating USB: full/persistent?

MOREOVER I'm running win 8.1 on my PC. How do I install that updatable USB in this case??

Comment: There are two ways of doing what you want. Please see the [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776?r=SearchResults&s=3|27.8069#295776) and edit your question. Questions about both the methods have been answered before. Please search old questions first.

Comment: Unplug your internal hard disk, plug in your USB and install Ubuntu to it just as you would to an internal drive using Live DVD or Live USB. The USB needs to be 8GB or larger.