# How to get Linux live kit to work?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, backup, iso, restricted-access

Does anyone know how to get Linux live kit to work on Ubuntu 20.04? I found [a website that showed me how](https://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/make-a-custom-live-linux-distro-with-linux-live-kit/), but when I tried to build it, the file would not show up. I tried rebooting but it did nothing. I know that Tmp empties on reboot, but when I try to make a directory like /build it says access denied.

Does anyone know how to get a bootable ISO using Linux live kit on Ubuntu 20.04?

I know how to use systemback and other tools.

Comment: You have an obsolete article. Creating a Live USB changed with 20.04. If your computer is UEFI, just format the USB to NTFS and extract the ISO to it using 7Zip, etc. Press ESC, F2, F9, F10, or F12, (depending on the computer make), to boot the drive. If your computer is BIOS boot try Etcher.

Comment: I understand that, but how do I get a working iso?

Comment: Could you tell me the steps please.

Comment: Also I would like to upload it to a vm

Comment: Have you considered doing a Full install to USB? this will give you an install that is the same as an internal install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1367263/43926 Once you have the USB install you can convert it to an .img or .vdi: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926