# Which one is better WSL2 or USB booted Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I have started to use WSL2 for a couple of weeks, and I quite enjoy it. I code as a hobby and sometimes for my work-related issues (physics-related stuff), but I am not a software developer or engineer.

Currently, I am using Windows10. However, I am thinking of using Ubuntu from now on and maybe choosing another distro in the future. Is USB bootable Ubuntu is a good option for the long run-or daily usage, or should I stay with the WSL2? I was thinking dual-boot, but I don't want to do that, I guess.

So, in summary, as a daily usage basis and for coding from time to time, should I ditch Windows10 and start to use Ubuntu via a USB bootable, or should I stay in windows but use WSL2?

The other thing is I don't know how the USB portable Ubuntu works for a long run ? Can I upload many files, use zoom ? How long one USB drive last ? Is it slower than dual-boot or WSL2 ? etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site for helping with Ubuntu related problems. Questions that seek opinions such as "which is better" is off topic here. See the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions in this site. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: USB flash drives do not have same life as SSD or HDD. Standard live installer does not save anything between reboots. You can add persistence if you have larger flash drive or do a full install from one flash drive to another. But my standard flash drives take over 45 min to install, where internal SSD is about 10 min. I have an SSD in USB3 adapter and full install is about 12 min. Or flash drives write very slow, but once installed & loaded into RAM run just as fast. Suggest external SSD as better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The other thing is I don't know how the USB portable Ubuntu works for
> a long run?

I have an USB portable Ubuntu full installation. I use it once a year. So far it has not failed.

> Can I upload many files, use zoom?

Uploading files to the cloud is limited by where you upload the files. I have not tried using Zoom from the USB full install, but I don't see any reason not to.

Yes you can store downloaded files in the internal drive, though that will not be the default location. Internal partitions, even Windows partitions (data and system) can be mounted in Ubuntu running from the USB. Once mounted,flies and folders can be written, stored, or saved in the internal partition.

> How long one USB drive last?

If you are like me, and use it once a year, it will last forever.

> Is it slower than dual-boot or WSL2?

Yes! USB drives are very slow. You can get an USB 3.0 or 3.2 and depending on your computer's USB port it can be a bit faster, but an installation in an internal drive, particularly a NVMe SSD will always be much faster than an USB.

An SSD in an enclosure with a SATA to USB or NVMe to USB interface would be faster and more durable than an USB flash drive. How fast will depend on your computer's USB port. If your computer has only USB 2.0 ports, then it won't be much faster than the USB flsh drive.

See [What would be the differences between a persistent USB Live Session and a installed Ubuntu in a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776) for more on different types of Ubuntu USB.

hope this helps

Comment: For downloading files part: for instance I am reading many article and they take space...USB device only starts the Ubuntu right?The files are stored in my interal drive? Well I want to use it daily..

Comment: @Omega So by "upload" you mean download!

Comment: yeah sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

> Is USB bootable Ubuntu is a good option for the long run-or daily usage, or should I stay with the WSL2?

Depends. USB drives usually aren't super fast (compared to an internal drive), even with USB 3.0 and above. I wouldn't suggest it, as dual-boot will be faster, and is more commonly used. I would dual-boot instead, but it is totally do-able if you setup persistence.

> So, in summary, as a daily usage basis and for coding from time to time, should I ditch Windows10 and start to use Ubuntu via a USB bootable, or should I stay in windows but use WSL2?

This is subjective. For just programming, WSL2 is just fine. But if you need something WSL cannot do, like access the webcam from Linux, you will need a proper Linux install, like on a USB stick or dual-boot.

> Can I upload many files, use zoom ?

I don't know what you mean by `upload many files`, but probobly. Ubuntu installed on a USB can do everything Ubuntu installed on a hard drive can. So yes, Zoom will work. That said, it might be slow, as even USB 3.0 drives aren't fast compared to a modern internal SSD.

> How long one USB drive last ?

Depends on many things such as how careful you are with it, the brand, how much you use it, the specific drive, and many other factors. The proper solution is to take regular backups *onto something other than the flash drive* so that if it fails, your files are not gone.

> Is it slower than dual-boot or WSL2 ?

I don't know what you mean by "slower". CPU benchmarks? Probobly faster. Disk benchmarks? Probobly slower, but depends on your flash drive and your system drive, of course.

Comment: For slower, I mean does the program lag or when I try to download something, it gets downloaded slower.. etc. For uploading files part: for instance I am reading many article and they take space...USB device only starts the Ubuntu right?The files are stored in my interal drive? Well I want to use it daily..