# Do applications installed in a live session need to be reinstalled after a reboot?

Tags: 18.04

If I install a specific application using "Try Ubuntu", is it necessary to reinstall the application every time I use the "Try Ubuntu" option?

Comment: To run a specific application that does not come with Ubuntu, it is best to fully install Ubuntu either in the internal drive or in a second (and bigger) USB drive. If you want to try the same dress everyday you have to go to the same store everyday, and you can't take the dress out of the store while trying it. See [this question for the difference between persistence and full install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal).

Comment: If you're just running a Live CD/DVD/USB without persistence, then yes, you will have to reinstall it in the Try Ubuntu option everytime.

Answer (score 3):

"Try Ubuntu" is also called a "live session" or "live USB".

The live USB is a full Ubuntu system that is loaded into RAM. The live system utilizes a read only SquashFS file system paired with an overlay file system that allows you to make changes during the live session on top of the read only system. However these changes do not survive a reboot.

Any changes you make during the live session are not permanent. The next time you use the "Try Ubuntu" option, it will be just like it was before you made any changes.

If you want changes to persist, you can research setting up "persistence" on the flash drive which allows you to retain the changes you make. This has limitations and performance implications because a liveUSB with persistence is still based on a read only file system with the overlay file system on top of it.

Alternatively, you can install Ubuntu to a USB flash drive. If you choose this type of installation, changes will persist just like they would if you had installed the OS to your hard drive.