# Live session: keeping changes after install?

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop from a USB stick. I've installed a couple of apps, made some changes to documents, put on a HOSTS file, keyboard shortcuts, that sort of thing. I'd like to go ahead and install it on the PC.

Is it possible to install and keep the changes I've made?

Comment: No, it isn't. Anything you do in a live session without persistence will 1. Be gone once you shutdown or reboot and 2. Won't be added to the installed system should you decide to install the OS within that live session.

Comment: Probably only the files and shortcuts if you back them up (copy) before you install.

Comment: You can do "history" and copy/paste the "apt" commands so you can do those after install. hosts you could copy contents too. The keyboard shortcuts will be in a file but re applying those will be quicker (and less problematic in case of issues).

Comment: That's what I thought, but for a brief moment I had hope. It's an inconvenience, but I'll survive. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You may find [this question and answers about persistent Live USB and Full install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776) useful.

Comment: There are several ways to run Ubuntu from a USB stick, including Live install, Persistent install and Full install. If you used a Full install you can just clone the USB to internal drive. If you used a Persistent Install, you can salvage the Home directory and most data. In a live install everything is lost on reboot.