# Installing Ubuntu on USB Flash Drive

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I know there are many answers to this question on `askubuntu` and `google.com`.

I have to ask for suggestions and difference between

> 1. Live USB
> 2. Installed USB

I want to install Ubuntu on Flash Drive so that I could use it on any system. Before that, I have some list of questions which requests answers to them.

> 1. Can an application be installed in **live mode** for later use
> 2. Which will be best : **live USB** or **installed USB**
> 3. Which bit version (**64 bit** or **32 bit**) will be suitable so that USB can be used to boot in systems with low configuration as well

I want this so that I could carry data and applications and boot using my USB and do my stuff from anywhere on any system and even If required the same USB could be used to install Ubuntu on other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible create a live USB that allows you to install apps and save that configuration, but it is *not recommended*.

The biggest difference between live and a full install is that on a live session, pretty much everything you run or install gets loaded into memory, and is lost when you reboot, unless you create a special live USB.

**My recommendation:** Install a lightweight, 32-bit version of Ubuntu, like [MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) or [LXDE](http://lubuntu.net/) onto your USB. Keep in mind that you'll need a speedy and fairly sized USB drive in order to get a pleasant experience.

*Cheers*

Comment: can this USB be used for installation of same OS on other systems as well without needing to create bootable USB again ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I mean, everything is possible on Linux, but you'd have to do some serious customization and digging in order to get that to work. You can however easily create bootable media from Ubuntu. Search for "USB" in the dash, and you'll find it.

Comment: I understand you, but what I want is a single USB with Ubuntu installed in it that can be used for carrying out stuffs on any system by booting from it and even it could work as a bootable installation medium that can be used to install Ubuntu on other system using this USB without need of creating another bootable installation USB.

Comment: In that case, take a look at this and see if it suits your needs: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Answer (score 2):

See [Difference between LiveCD, LiveUSB, full-install, and persistence?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156026/difference-between-livecd-liveusb-full-install-and-persistence) for comparison between Live Persistent and Full installs.

Mkusb makes a persistent install that pretty much closes the gap between Live and Persistent installs, the persistent boot takes a little longer and installing proprietary drivers is still not possible.

A mkusb drive can be used to install Ubuntu.