# Changing network setup persistently in a live Kubuntu installation

Tags: networking, kubuntu, live-usb

I created a live Kubuntu persistent installation using mkusb. This was the only tool that could create a working Kubuntu installation for my macbook. It works properly and changes are kept after the reboot, but with some exceptions: some properties set in the network manager are not saved at all. For instance if I try to add additional DNS addresses or set password for a VPN setup, those are not saved. Reboot is not needed to clear those props, just closing the dialog and reopening it and the prop is lost. Also when changing values the apply button is always disabled.

Anyone else experiencing the same on a live installation? Any way to set those properties persistently somehow?

Comment: The way to set it permanently is with a installation. A live session with or without persistence is not that.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I tried already many many times: live using mkusb is the only way I could make it boot on the macbook. There are still a few guides I'm missing, but at this point I prefer not to invest more time on this. Fixing this would be enough for the moment.

Comment: @sudodus, the developer of mkusb may have some ideas.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/156026/difference-between-livecd-liveusb-full-install-and-persistence

Comment: That is intetesting, but how can that answer the question? You mean that I should edit the casper-rw file?