# Is there a way to boot ubuntu from an USB and record all changes made during the usage?

Tags: boot, 18.04

Is there a way to boot ubuntu from an USB and record all changes made during the boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb)

Comment: If you are booting in persistent mode, you can look in the casper-rw file or partition for changes, all changes are saved there. It is easier to look into a casper-rw partition than into a casper-rw file. Mkusb creates a Persistent drive that uses a casper-rw partition. If you have a Full install to USB you can use something like fswatch, Fswatch is a free, open source multi-platform file change monitor utility that notifies us when the contents of the specified files or directories are modified or changed. Not for beginners. https://www.ostechnix.com/monitor-file-changes-using-fswatch-linux//

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)