# Regarding boot my pendrive to fomat my windows to ubuntu

Tags: boot, rufus

[image]

I can not boot my pen drive. After 100% this message is coming how can I fix it? Any information will be helpful.

Comment: I format my pendrive many times but nothing happen.

Comment: @akeo, Can you help this user?

Comment: Can you provide more information? It looks like you are trying to format the disk at the same time you are flashing the ISO.  That's not going to work.  Are you unable to format or flash the USB separately? Because that could be a sign that the USB flash drive is dead

Comment: Problem is that when the status is showing failed at the same time this window is coming that "You need to format the disk"

Comment: First I format my USB drive then I started. But this is coming again and again.

Comment: @Nmath  I was following this actually
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb#:~:text=Rufus%20is%20able%20to%20create,size%20of%20more%20than%204GB.

Comment: Try formatting via the "The Command Line Way" answer lower down here https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive but BE CAREFUL that you triple check that the drive name is in fact the USB Flash and not one of your hard drives or you will screw the pooch. And yes make it FAT32 like that example. Then again being very carefull, put the ISO directly onto this newly formatted USB Flash using dd command `dd if=/pathtomyfile/my.iso of=/dev/sda?(or whatever) bs=1M` and let us know.

Comment: Which method on that link were you following?

Comment: @karel Actually, at this moments I am using windows 7, but I want to use Ubuntu. For this reason I have to boot my pen drive. For this I have installed properly the Rufus software for boot my pen drive in windows operating system. But in this boot process I am facing trouble. But the link which you provide is for Ubuntu operating system. Am I right?