# Can I install files on my bootable Ubuntu usb drive?Will it affect the installation?

Tags: boot, 20.04, files, live-usb

Can I make a folder with files that I need without corrupting/interrupting the installation?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776) will help you. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1393262/edit) if you still have questions after reading that question and answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb)

Answer (score 1):

As long you are using a persistent USB and not a Live or Full install USB you should be okay.

A Persistent USB stores new data in an overlay file or partition, (named "writable"), that is not used for the install to the computer.