# Ubuntu 20.04 USB not working after every reboot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, usb, initramfs

Okay so... This is kind of a follow-up.
I formatted with Rufus a 128Gb USB 3.1 (gen 1) with a 116Gb GPT persistent partition and I'm using NTFS with a 4096 cluster.
Everythings fine, I install Gnome Tweaks, Dconfig Editor, update the whole thing with Software Update, download the propietary Nvidia drivers, you know... But then I reboot via terminal/button on the desktop and everything's gone. When I try to boot from the USB it takes me to the GRUB menu, I click Ubuntu, Ubuntu Safe Graphics and it just goes 0.365513 Initramfs unpacking failed/0.365282 Initramfs unpacking failed/similars that I didn't even wrote down. Then it just says "Unable to find medium container a live file system" but no key works nor does anything, I've formatted the same USB about 4 times today, it keeps happening and I don't know why. I just want a live usb I can use between my desktop pc and laptop, please.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu with NTFS? .You should try with FAT32.@EIFrutero

Comment: @PiyushMhatre Really? I read about it and apparently I can't store files larger than 4GB, I want to use this live USB as a sorta main drive for my laptop and a secondary for my desktop, that would involve stuff like downloading games, video files... you know, stuff that weighs more than 4GB, but I'll give it a try, this problem makes me have to reinstall the ISO after every reboot

Comment: Ok try EX FAT and if it doesn't work then keep your usb on MBR partitioning scheme. @Rick_afk

Comment: A few things wrong. You should never do a software update on a Live USB. Updates quickly fill the persistent file / partition and the USB will not boot. A live USB can not be upgraded as the kernel is part of a read only file. Proprietary, (Nvidia), drivers do not work as they need to be loaded before the persistence overlay but the command to load them is in the overlay. Some tools like YUMI and Universal work well with NTFS and Ubuntu, not Rufus. sounds to me like you need a Full install to USB, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Comment: or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: Oooookay... Wow, didn't even know that thanks, does that mean that in order to use the usb as I want to (Like if it was an ssd or something) I need to make a Full installation? @C.S.Cameron Still, thanks for the info... I'm learning a lot here

Comment: A Full install to USB will do everything that a Full install to internal disk will do, only a little more slowly. https://askubuntu.com/questions/156026/difference-between-livecd-liveusb-full-install-and-persistence/396219#396219

Comment: Oh wow, I'll give it a try tomorrow, I've been doing this for almost 12 hours, good night and thanks! @C.S.Cameron

Answer (score 0):

### Advantages of a Persistent install

1. You can use the Persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A Persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the Persistent pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The Persistent install to pendrive takes less time.
5. Slightly less wear on the drive.

### Advantages of a Full install

1. You can update and upgrade a Full Install.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can encrypt a Full Install.
5. You can use proprietary drivers.
6. Hibernation works.
7. There is no 4GB casper-rw or 4GB home-rw persistence file size limitation.
8. Generally faster boot than Live or Persistent USBs.
9. More stable.

Comment: Okay, I did it yesterday, it took around 12 hours to install from USB 2.0 to my other USB. It said that it was ready but now it doesn't even work, I can go to the GRUB menu and click Ubuntu as much as I want but nothing will happen

Comment: Usually only takes me under an hour using flash drive on  USB2. What installer program did you use, Rufus? I will  get back to you in the morning USB2.

Comment: Thanks, I'll describe the process, I formatted the USB3 just in case with rufus, then used BalenaEtcher to write the ISO into the USB2, I logged into the live USB and then installed via Ubuntu Installation, re-formatted the USB3 and then clicked the Install button, it took 12 (maybe 14, I went to sleep).

Comment: Now when I try to boot it appears as if it made a GRUB thing in my main drive (which it shouldn't had to). It takes me to the GRUB menu with or without USB, even if the USB is plugged in nothing will happen, it'll just stand there doing nothing for half an hour, I would've tried waiting longer but I have classes

Comment: If you are trying to do an install to USB the same as to internal drive it is recommended to unplug any Windows drive first. Default install puts boot loader on sda. For making your first Full install to USB I recommend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi For those whith lots of experience installing Ubuntu I recommend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: Ooooh I tried using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIhYitXwJfE&ab_channel=LiamRoberts I'll have to give it another shot at Friday because I can't simply afford to have my computer essentially shut down for 13-14 hours on a work-week, okay so I'll try doing the full install on the usb while also disconnecting both my ssd and hdd, got it. Thank you man, I'll keep you posted