# Install Ubuntu from USB Stick to USB Stick and use it as “external drive” to boot and use from

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive, usb-installation

I would like to understand if it is possible to install Ubuntu from an USB Stick on another USB Stick (256 GB) and use this USB stick to boot from and use Ubuntu like it is installed on my notebook with all the featured and also write back files etc. on my USB stick.

Is this possible? And is there a difference between installing Ubuntu on USB Stick and installing Ubuntu on an external SSD Drive? Are there any limitations/restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

### Installing Full Ubuntu on USB Stick.

A comparison of Full install vs Persistent install can be found here: [Ubuntu 20.04 USB not working after every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310302/ubuntu-20-04-usb-not-working-after-every-reboot/1310335#1310335)

A quick and easy method to flash a Full install of Ubuntu to USB can be found here: [Easy Full Install USB that Boots both BIOS and UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi)

A step by step method of Fully installing Ubuntu to USB can be found here: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

Both of these methods work with SSD's, Flash Drives and other External USB drives.

Comment: Thanks, i will check this and get with feedback mark as answer.

Comment: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. (I have not had that work, but others have.)
Or if you have ESP on second or external drive, you can just reinstall grub, either manually or using Boot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall to correct drive.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is possible to do so. Long time ago I did this an I remember there have been problems for me but I don't remebmber details. Then I found out that there are tools to create live USB drives with persistence.

There are multiple tools to create those.
For Windows there is Rufus and Yumi.
For Linux there is UNetbootin,MultiBootUSB and my absolute favorite since I found out about it some month ago is Ventoy