# Trouble with full USB Install

Tags: boot, partitioning, software-installation, usb

This has been a series of events, somebody told me to do a full USB install instead of a live USB.
It took about 13-14 hours the first 2 times, then I did it again just today+recommendations that people told me like disconnecting all other drives, etc. Same thing as the past 2 times happened, the process had supposedly finished correctly but nothing, the "Fully Installed USB" is not even detected in my BIOS as a drive of neither my laptop or dekstop.

I initially followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIhYitXwJfE&ab_channel=LiamRoberts) to do the Full Installation, ext4, use all the space, press - to clear the space, what am I doing wrong? I just want a usb that I can use Ubuntu in but also update drivers and software.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is video for UEFI or BIOS install? MBR or gpt partitioned drive.If using USB3 device & USB3 ports it should not take that long. In fact my full install to an external SSD was not much longer than a full install to internal SSD and a bit faster than to internal HDD. I prefer to partition in advance with gpt. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Oh yeah sorry:
Live USB from where I'm installing Ubuntu into the other USB stick: USB 2.0, 32GB, No persistent Partition, FAT32.
The drive where I'm trying to fully install Ubuntu: USB 3.1 (gen. 1) 128GB. Supposedly the whole unit as a single ext4 partition.

I'm doing both with GPT since some people told me that's why Rufus was taking 2 hours to format the drives, BIOS.

Comment: If hardware is UEFI, I prefer UEFI/gpt install. But you need an ESP - efi system partition. Where I normally suggest 300 to 500MB for larger drives, you can use 100MB for ESP. It would not be large enough for dual booting with SystemD boot, but you do not normally dual boot a flash drive. I use 100MB ESP, 30GB / (root) and rest as data partition or you can make it /home or just / if desired. External drives only boot from ESP. Ubiquity only installs grub to first drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311384/install-ubuntu-from-usb-stick-to-usb-stick-and-use-it-as-external-drive-to-boo